# Windows 11 Widgets Not Opening Intel UHD 10th Generation

Tags: windows, windows-11, widgets

`Windows 11` widgets are not running at all. GPU: `Intel UHD 10th Generation`

After a clean installation, they were working.
After updating `Windows` they still worked.
After updating the `Store` apps, the widgets stopped running.

- I'm signed in with a `Microsoft` account.
- Rebooted.
- Tried disabling the graphics.
- Edge is the only and default browser.

Please help.

OS: `Windows 11 Build 10.0.22000.258`

`Microsoft Edge` is the default and only web browser on the device.

Signed in with a `Microsoft` account.

Microsoft `WebView2 94.0.992.47` x64 is installed.

There are no 3rd party apps installed.

Comment: Windows 11 Widgets are a work in progress.  Try running Updates including Optional, restart and check.  My widgets are running currently but a while back they did not work.

Comment: I restarted the computer and the explorer but it did not work.    .......     If this is Production Windows 11 (from this past October 5 and not a VM, then enter a Microsoft support case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resolved after Microsoft released an update to `Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime`, to version `94.0.992.50`.

Widgets do not work in earlier versions of `Edge WebView2 Runtime`.

| UHD 10th driver version | WebView2 | Widgets | Microsoft Teams | 3rd party apps |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27.20.100.8935 | 94.0.992.50 | Does not work properly | Does not work properly | OK |
| **30.0.100.9894 Beta** | 94.0.992.50 | OK | OK | OK |
| 30.0.100.9955 | 94.0.992.50 | OK | Does not work properly | Does not work properly |
| **31.0.101.2114** | 107.0.1418.35 | OK | OK | OK |

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following steps.

(Check you're already turned on the Widgets option in settings. Make sure you're login into a Microsoft account instead of the local account.)

If it's still not working, open Task Manager then restart Windows Explorer.

If the problem is still there, open Task Manager once again then right-click on Windows Widgets and End Task.

Reboot.

Comment: I restarted the computer and the explorer but it did not work. I disabled widgets and enabled it again but it did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

from PowerShell as administrator run:

```
winget uninstall "windows web experience pack"
```

after that install it again from:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-web-experience-pack/9mssgkg348sp